# ASP.NET Core MVC equivalent of Start Action Specific Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-debugging

In `ASP.NET Webforms` or `ASP.NET MVC` projects, I can select the page/route that is being called in the browser when I press F5 for debugging, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Specific page setting]

What is the equivalent in `ASP.NET Core MVC`? I'm using `IIS Express` with `SSL` for local debugging. In the `launchSettings.json` I have an `applicationUrl` defined as this:

```
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59563/",
  "sslPort": 44333
}
```

When I start debugging, `https://localhost:44333` is called. My goal is to that `https://localhost:44333/MYROUTE` is beging called upon starting the debug mode.

Where can I specify that I want `https://localhost:44333/MYROUTE` to be my start URL for debugging?

Comment: app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=MYROUTE}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
would not this work ?@citronas

Comment: That would require that I need to make a change in the code directly and something I would like to avoid as I think that the settings for debugging should not be stored in code but rather in a configuration file.

Comment: What about adding an environment variable and deciding on the basis of its value. I mean if value is debug use the above mentioned setting else use default setting. Just a suggestion @citronas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `launchUrl` setting with a relative url:

```
"launchUrl": "Home/About",
```

You can also set this from the project properties in Visual Studio:

[image]

This will start the browser with the specificed relative url:

[image]

Comment: Okay, I definetly had a weird corner case that affected my debugging. I created a new controller named 'CodificationController" and upon calling the /Codification route I received a 'HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure'. Seems to be special case of a reserved keyword that I can't use. Upon renaming my controller, everything works just fine with the launchUrl. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can change the launchsettings.json (in Visual Studio usually shown when you expand the "Properties"-Node in the solution explorer. There you can set the launchUrl in the according launch profile:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59563/",
     "sslPort": 44333
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
     "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44333/YOURROUTE"
    }
}
```

You can select the launch profile using the small black arrow next to the debug-button:
[image: Set launch profile]