# How to config ASP.NET Core startup route (like in previous version of ASP.NET MVC 5)?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

In previous version of ASP.NET MVC 5, when you start project using <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>, the route of current working file in vs will set to browser for example:

when you're editing `about.cshtml` from `home` controller and you start project, the browser will come up with `localhost/home/about` route.

I've tried checking configs of an mvc5 project but just found nothing.

My question is: how can I config the ASP.NET Core MVC project to behave like this?

Thanks

---

Update:

I found [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57268200/asp-net-core-mvc-equivalent-of-start-action-specific-page) that is near to my question, In my case I need "current page" option in ASP.NET Core

[image: strat action current page]

Answer (score 0):

[This feature is applicable in asp.net core project.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/property-pages-settings-for-web-projects?view=vs-2022#start-options-category)

[image]

**Workaround**

If you need this, you can set launch url like below:

[image]

It same as add `launch url` in `launchSettings.json`.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, so i got something, but the setting that i'm looking for is not a static  url, i found start url that you mentioned it, in mvc version it has "current page" but this option is missing in core